# Alternative approach for multiple button click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-click, alternate

I am just wondering is there any better way to approach same kind of logic as below. 4 buttons onclick of it have to send parameters like (english, german, spanish, french) to angular function. Is there any possibility to reduce repetition of code here by using model binding or array or enum??

Even following approach may or may not be the best way to handle it. Since I am not that proficient in angular I am not sure about better alternative approach. Please advice.

**Basically is there any way to implement same logic in a better way??**

Note: I am using angular 1.7.2 version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Demo</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

                <script>
                    var app = angular.module('app', []);
                    app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                    $scope.Language = 'German';
                        $scope.Preference = function(lang) {
                           $scope.Language = lang;
                        };  

                    }]);
                </script>
                </head>
            <body>
                    <h2>Attach functions or behavior - AngularJS</h2>
                <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
                Click 
                <button ng-click="Preference('English')">English</button>
        <button ng-click="Preference('German')">German</button>
        <button ng-click="Preference('Spanish')">Spanish</button>
        <button ng-click="Preference('French')">French</button>
                <p>I like {{ Language}}</p>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat` for the buttons and an array for the values. Also you can avoid using function by using `ng-click` to set the selected value:

```
<button ng-repeat="lan in vm.languages" ng-click="vm.Preference(lan)">{{lan}}</button>
```

Check a demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z8g2kpy1/2/)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But I have some more logic involved on click of the button not just assigning values, like if mobile update "I like text" else don't change it. Also its responsive website.  If screen is mobile put two buttons top and two buttons on next line.

Comment: Ok I see. You can keep the function then and use `ng-repeat` for the buttons. I will edit the answer

Comment: Let me know is it possible to use above repeat logic if I have design concerns for responsive website?? For example I have to add margin bottom for third button in the repeat

Comment: Yes you can use `ng-class` with $index like this: `ng-class="{ 'btn-3': $index==2 }"`. Check here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9L52je4/2/)